# PayPal REST API Malformed JSON error

Tags: php, json, api, rest, paypal

I'm trying to get the "Pay with PayPal account" working with PHP and I keep getting the response "Incoming JSON request does not map to API request".
I have checked the JSON that I'm sending with jsonlint and it is valid JSON.  It also appears to match what is being send in the sample for this payment type.

```php
require __DIR__ . '/../bootstrap.php';
use PayPal\Api\Amount;
use PayPal\Api\Details;
use PayPal\Api\Item;
use PayPal\Api\ItemList;
use PayPal\Api\Payer;
use PayPal\Api\Payment;
use PayPal\Api\RedirectUrls;
use PayPal\Api\Transaction;
session_start();

// ### Payer
$payer = new Payer();
$payer->setPaymentMethod("paypal");

// ### Itemized information
$item1 = new Item();
$item1->setName($item1Name)
    ->setCurrency($currency)
    ->setQuantity($item1Quantity)
    ->setPrice($item1Price);
$item2 = new Item();
$item2->setName($item2Name)
    ->setCurrency($currency)
    ->setQuantity($item2Quantity)
    ->setPrice($item2Price);

$itemList = new ItemList();
$itemList->setItems(array($item1, $item2));

// ### Additional payment details
$details = new Details();
$details->setShipping($shipping)
    ->setTax($tax)
    ->setSubtotal($subtotal);

// ### Amount
$amount = new Amount();
$amount->setCurrency($currency)
    ->setTotal(number_format(($subtotal + ($shipping + $tax)), 2))
    ->setDetails($subtotal);

// ### Transaction
$transaction = new Transaction();
$transaction->setAmount($amount)
    ->setItemList($itemList)
    ->setDescription("Payment description");

// ### Redirect urls
$baseUrl = getBaseUrl();
$redirectUrls = new RedirectUrls();
$redirectUrls->setReturnUrl("$baseUrl/ExecutePayment.php?success=true")
    ->setCancelUrl("$baseUrl/ExecutePayment.php?success=false");

// ### Payment
$payment = new Payment();
$payment->setIntent("sale")
    ->setPayer($payer)
    ->setRedirectUrls($redirectUrls)
    ->setTransactions(array($transaction));

// ### Create Payment
$payment->create($apiContext);
} catch (PayPal\Exception\PPConnectionException $ex) {
    echo "Exception: " . $ex->getMessage() . PHP_EOL;
    var_dump($ex->getData());   
    exit(1);
}

// ### Get redirect url
foreach($payment->getLinks() as $link) {
    if($link->getRel() == 'approval_url') {
        $redirectUrl = $link->getHref();
        break;
    }
}

// ### Redirect buyer to PayPal website
$_SESSION['paymentId'] = $payment->getId();
if(isset($redirectUrl)) {
    header("Location: $redirectUrl");
    exit;
}
```

The PayPal.log contains the following:

```
PayPal\Core\PPHttpConnection: Connecting to https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token
PayPal\Core\PPHttpConnection: Payload grant_type=client_credentials
PayPal\Core\PPHttpConnection: Adding header User-Agent: PayPalSDK/rest-sdk-php 0.6.0 (lang=PHP;v=5.3.3;bit=64;os=********************;machine=x86_64;openssl=**********;curl=7.15.5)
PayPal\Core\PPHttpConnection: Adding header Authorization: Basic ***********************************
PayPal\Core\PPHttpConnection: Adding header Accept: */*
PayPal\Core\PPHttpConnection: Connecting to https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment
PayPal\Core\PPHttpConnection: Payload {"intent":"sale","payer":{"payment_method":"paypal"},"redirect_urls":{"return_url":"http:\/\/www.mysite.com\/paypal-test\/sample\/payments\/ExecutePayment.php?success=true","cancel_url":"http:\/\/www.mysite.com\/paypal-test\/sample\/payments\/ExecutePayment.php?success=false"},"transactions":[{"amount":{"currency":"EUR","total":"554.00","details":"550.00"},"item_list":{"items":[{"name":"Item 1 Name","currency":"EUR","quantity":50,"price":"7.00"},{"name":"Item 2 Name","currency":"EUR","quantity":20,"price":"10.00"}]},"description":"Payment description"}]}
PayPal\Core\PPHttpConnection: Adding header Content-Type: application/json
PayPal\Core\PPHttpConnection: Adding header User-Agent: PayPalSDK/rest-sdk-php 0.6.0 (lang=PHP;v=5.3.3;bit=64;os=*******************;machine=x86_64;openssl=************;curl=7.15.5)
PayPal\Core\PPHttpConnection: Adding header Authorization: Bearer gSJ0P0foNQcWg3V76VjvSietNLejlF4-kfSFNkTcyCk
PayPal\Core\PPHttpConnection: Adding header PayPal-Request-Id: 773226502471885139220716063968
```

Any help is very much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have figured it out.  I was passing a number into the Amount->SetDetails and not the object that was required.

    // ### Amount
    $amount = new Amount();
    $amount->setCurrency($currency)
    ->setTotal(number_format(($subtotal + ($shipping + $tax)), 2))
    ->setDetails($subtotal);

One thing that helped me to figure it out was comparing the logs of the PayPal sample (/sample/PayPal.log) with the log of my own attempt.

Disaster averted!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have figured it out.  I was passing a number into the Amount->SetDetails and not the object that was required.

```
// ### Amount
$amount = new Amount();
$amount->setCurrency($currency)
->setTotal(number_format(($subtotal + ($shipping + $tax)), 2))
->setDetails($subtotal);
```

One thing that helped me to figure it out was comparing the logs of the PayPal sample (/sample/PayPal.log) with the log of my own attempt.

Disaster averted!